# Store DB columns values to string in Groovy

Tags: sql, groovy, soapui

I am trying to store Sql query result to string.

```
def DBlist = con.rows("select a.pkResourceItemsID,b.fieldValue,a.fkResourceID,a.fkCountryID,b.fkLocationID,b.fkBusinessUnitID,b.floor from tblResourceItems a inner join tblresourceitemData b on a.pkResourceItemsID=b.fkResourceItemID where a.pkResourceItemsID='$id'" )

log.info "DB_List = ${DBlist}"
```

The result I am getting:

```
DB_List =[[pkResourceItemsID:2000, fieldValue:Hello, fkResourceID:1, fkCountryID:1, fkLocationID:88, fkBusinessUnitID:518, floor:1]]
```

The result I want :

```
DB_List =[2000, Hello, 1, 1, 88, 518, 1]
```

What I have tried :

```
def a = DBlist.pkResourceItemsID
```

It Gives me result `[2000]`, but I can only do this for one column at a time.

Don't know how to do for all the columns. How can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Sql.rows(GString query)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/index.html?overview-summary.html) returns a [`List<GroovyRowResult>`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/GroovyRowResult.html) this is why when you make a `println` of your returned object you get:

```
[[pkResourceItemsID:2000, fieldValue:Hello, fkResourceID:1, fkCountryID:1, fkLocationID:88, fkBusinessUnitID:518, floor:1]]
```

If instead of this you want simply a list with only the result values you can perform the follow operation on the object returned by `Sql.rows()` method call as:

```
// for each row in the result list
def rowResults = DBlist.collect{ row ->
    // get only the column values
    row.keySet().collect { row[it] }
}
```

This is a generic approach since `rows()` returns multiple results, now you've a list of lists where each list only contains the values.

If you're interested only in the first result; get the first object in that list:

```
println rowResults[0] 
// [2000, Hello, 1, 1, 88, 518, 1]
```

#### Another approach: use `firstRow` instead

If your query it's designed to get only one result, use [`firstRow()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#firstRow(groovy.lang.GString)) instead of `rows()`, this way you'll have directly a `GroovyRowResult` instead of `List<GroovyRowResult>`, and then you can get all values without the column names easily:

```
def DBlist = con.firstRow("select a.pkResourceItemsID,b.fieldValue,a.fkResourceID,a.fkCountryID,b.fkLocationID,b.fkBusinessUnitID,b.floor from tblResourceItems a inner join tblresourceitemData b on a.pkResourceItemsID=b.fkResourceItemID where a.pkResourceItemsID='$id'" )

def rowValues = DBlist.keySet().collect { DBlist[it] }
println rowValues
// [2000, Hello, 1, 1, 88, 518, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.
But both the solution gives null alert popup.

Comment: @rAJ the popup maybe it's due to some other code, add `return;` to the end of your script to avoid it.